# How to have gaps in xychart

Tags: amcharts

Its mentioned on amchart documentation that

> connect: false

is not available for xy chart [amGraph](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph). Still if there is any trick to solve it.
Any help will be appreciated.

I have a xy amchart and want to show gap in its average.
I am using cx and cy to plot average graph which doesn't have its data point for cx = 7,8,9,10.
Still the final graph has continuous line for average.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "ax": 1,
    "ay": 0.5,
    "bx": 1,
    "by": 2.2,
    "cx": 1,
    "cy": 1
  }, {
    "ax": 2,
    "ay": 1.3,
    "bx": 2,
    "by": 4.9,
    "cx": 2,
    "cy": 3
  }, {
    "ax": 3,
    "ay": 2.3,
    "bx": 3,
    "by": 5.1,
    "cx": 3,
    "cy": 4.5
  }, {
    "ax": 4,
    "ay": 2.8,
    "bx": 4,
    "by": 5.3,
    "cx": 4,
    "cy": 4
  }, {
    "ax": 5,
    "ay": 3.5,
    "bx": 5,
    "by": 6.1,
    "cx": 5,
    "cy": 5
  }, {
    "ax": 6,
    "ay": 5.1,
    "bx": 6,
    "by": 8.3,
    "cx": 6,
    "cy": 6.5
  }, {
    "ax": 7,
    "ay": 6.7,
    "bx": 7,
    "by": 10.5
  }, {
    "ax": 8,
    "ay": 8,
    "bx": 8,
    "by": 12.3
  }, {
    "ax": 9,
    "ay": 8.9,
    "bx": 9,
    "by": 14.5
  }, {
    "ax": 10,
    "ay": 9.7,
    "bx": 10,
    "by": 15
  }, {
    "ax": 11,
    "ay": 10.4,
    "bx": 11,
    "by": 18.8,
    "cx": 11,
    "cy": 14.5
  }, {
    "ax": 12,
    "ay": 11.7,
    "bx": 12,
    "by": 21,
    "cx": 12,
    "cy": 16
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "id": "x",
    "title": "X Axis"
  }, {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "id": "y",
    "title": "Y Axis"
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "x:[[ax]] y:[[ay]]",
    "fillAlphas": 0.3,
    "fillToAxis": "x",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay",
    "lineColor": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[bx]] y:[[by]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "fillToAxis": "y",
    "fillAlphas": 0.3,
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by",
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[cx]] y:[[cy]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "cx",
    "yField": "cy",
    "forcegap": true,
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  } ],
  "marginLeft": 64,
  "marginBottom": 60,
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "chartCursor": {},
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "position": "bottom-right"
  }
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width  : 100%;
 height  : 500px;
 font-size : 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to simulate a gap in the XY chart type is to create separate graph objects for each segment. This will essentially force a disconnect by creating a brand new line starting at the next set of points. Using your demo as an example, you need to create new properties called c2x and c2y for the subsequent values after cx > 10:

```
    {
    "ax": 11,
    "ay": 10.4,
    "bx": 11,
    "by": 18.8,
    "c2x": 11, //change from cx to c2x
    "c2y": 14.5 //change from cy to c2y
  }, {
    "ax": 12,
    "ay": 11.7,
    "bx": 12,
    "by": 21,
    "c2x": 12,
    "c2y": 16
  }],
  // ...
  "graphs": [
   // ...
  { //add new graph for the next segment
    "balloonText": "x:[[c2x]] y:[[c2y]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "c2x",
    "yField": "c2y",
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  }]
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "ax": 1,
    "ay": 0.5,
    "bx": 1,
    "by": 2.2,
    "cx": 1,
    "cy": 1
  }, {
    "ax": 2,
    "ay": 1.3,
    "bx": 2,
    "by": 4.9,
    "cx": 2,
    "cy": 3
  }, {
    "ax": 3,
    "ay": 2.3,
    "bx": 3,
    "by": 5.1,
    "cx": 3,
    "cy": 4.5
  }, {
    "ax": 4,
    "ay": 2.8,
    "bx": 4,
    "by": 5.3,
    "cx": 4,
    "cy": 4
  }, {
    "ax": 5,
    "ay": 3.5,
    "bx": 5,
    "by": 6.1,
    "cx": 5,
    "cy": 5
  }, {
    "ax": 6,
    "ay": 5.1,
    "bx": 6,
    "by": 8.3,
    "cx": 6,
    "cy": 6.5
  }, {
    "ax": 7,
    "ay": 6.7,
    "bx": 7,
    "by": 10.5
  }, {
    "ax": 8,
    "ay": 8,
    "bx": 8,
    "by": 12.3
  }, {
    "ax": 9,
    "ay": 8.9,
    "bx": 9,
    "by": 14.5
  }, {
    "ax": 10,
    "ay": 9.7,
    "bx": 10,
    "by": 15
  }, {
    "ax": 11,
    "ay": 10.4,
    "bx": 11,
    "by": 18.8,
    "c2x": 11,
    "c2y": 14.5
  }, {
    "ax": 12,
    "ay": 11.7,
    "bx": 12,
    "by": 21,
    "c2x": 12,
    "c2y": 16
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "bottom",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "id": "x",
    "title": "X Axis"
  }, {
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "id": "y",
    "title": "Y Axis"
  } ],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [ {
    "balloonText": "x:[[ax]] y:[[ay]]",
    "fillAlphas": 0.3,
    "fillToAxis": "x",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "ax",
    "yField": "ay",
    "lineColor": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[bx]] y:[[by]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "fillToAxis": "y",
    "fillAlphas": 0.3,
    "xField": "bx",
    "yField": "by",
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[cx]] y:[[cy]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "cx",
    "yField": "cy",
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "balloonText": "x:[[c2x]] y:[[c2y]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "xField": "c2x",
    "yField": "c2y",
    "lineColor": "#FCD202"
  } ],
  "marginLeft": 64,
  "marginBottom": 60,
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "chartCursor": {},
  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "position": "bottom-right"
  }
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width  : 100%;
 height  : 500px;
 font-size : 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @xorspark for your suggestion but it might work in a case when there are finite no of breaks.  
What if we don't know the no of breaks/gaps?

Comment: That's your only option with XY charts as it does not support gaps natively at all. You can create logic to detect your breaks and dynamically create your graph objects and adjust accordingly. Your only other alternative is to use serial charts but you'll have to fill in empty points for the numeric X axis labels as serial charts do not support numeric category axis.